# picture download difference between PC and WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, download, image

in WP7 I try to download a graphic from yahoo, e.g.:

http://chart.finance.yahoo.com/z?s=PLX12.NYM&t=1d&q=l&l=on&z=m&a=v&p=s

on my PC it works as expected, but not on my Windows phone, no difference if I do it in my app or just simple directly in the WP7 browser. You can try it simply by yourself. On the WP7/8 emulators it works sometimes, but not always.
It seems in WP7 the parameters are differently interpreted as on my PC. Anyone an idea what's the reason for this?

Thanks for help

Hanno

Comment: Can you show us the code you use to you download it?

Comment: I would expect that this is due to Yahoo using the useragent of the request to detect what is making the request and then returning a different response based on that (so that it returns something appropriate to the agent making the request). Your link is currently returning a, default, "chart not available" image for all requests at the moment so can't investigate further.

Answer (score 0):

I quickly threw this together, and it worked on my Win8 emulator and my Windows Phone 7.1. Just need to set the useragent to trick Yahoo into thinking we're a desktop ;)

```cs
public void LoadImage(Image imageControl, string imageUrl)
{
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    client.Headers["UserAgent"] = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)";
    client.OpenReadCompleted += new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(OpenReadCompleted);
    client.OpenReadAsync(new Uri(imageUrl, UriKind.Absolute)); 
}

private void OpenReadCompleted(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();  
    image.SetSource(e.Result);
    imageControl.Source = image;
}
```

You can then call that function from wherever you want, using an Image control (on your page) and a url. I used this one, as yours seems to be invalid:
http://chart.finance.yahoo.com/z?s=MSFT&t=1d&q=l&l=on&z=m&a=v&p=s

EDIT:
Removed the complete function from the lambda expression and gave it its own. Much less lazy.